# PHPUnit фильтрация некоторых тестов

Tags: php, юнит-тесты, phpunit

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать следующее: У меня есть проект, который нужно протестировать unit-тестами, тестов много и процентов 20 из них не запускаются и тестирование завершается с ошибками (и тут проблемы не столько в тестировании самой системы, сколько в самих тестах, так как тесты от другой версии системы). И вот как сконфигурировать конфиг, чтобы пропускать такие тесты?

Сейчас у меня примерно так:

```
<testsuite>
    <directory>modules</directory>
</testsuite>
</testsuites>
<filter>
    <blacklist>
        <directory>./modules/Administration</directory>   
    </blacklist>
</filter>
```

Вот так я пытаюсь фильтровать тесты: `./modules/Administration`, но что-то не получается.

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить в тег `<exclude></exclude>` путь к ненужным тестам.

Линк:  [`Test Suite`](http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.testsuites)

В вашей ситуации это будет выглядеть вот так:

```
<testsuites>
   <testsuite name="main">
        <directory suffix=".php">./modules</directory>
        <exclude>./modules/Administration</exclude>
   </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Обращение к этому набору:

```
> phpunit --testsuite main
```

То что вы пытались использовать, `filter` и `blacklist` - это относиться к файлам для сборщика отчета `CodeCoverage`.

Линк: [`Including and Excluding Files for Code Coverage`](http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.blacklist-whitelist)

P.S.: если у вас будет один набор тестов и у него не будет имени, то передавать параметром `--testsuite main` не нужно. Просто помните, что при добавлении следующих наборов, безымянные и именованные будут попадать под общую выборку, если не передать параметр в `phpunit`.